# Past tense and present perfect

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I want to know whether my daughter drank all her milk that I <del>have given</del> gave <del>it</del> to her 10 minutes ago; should I say

> Have you drunk your milk?

or

> Did you drink your milk?

or

> Have you finished your milk?

or

> Did you finish your milk?

Comment: Least likely in my neck of the woods is "Have you drunk" but all are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sentences are grammatically correct; the OP can use any of them in the context presented.

In BE, you use ony the present perfect for recent actions. So you don't use the past simple here.

On the other hand, Americans tend to use the past simple for recent actions, but the present perfect is also possible. So all the sentences are correct in AE.

Answer (score 1):

*10 minutes ago* is a finished time expression.
The past tense is used for a finished action at a specific point in the past.

When using the perfect tense, we're focusing in the present.

Comment: He **gave** it to her 10 minutes ago. But she could **have finished** it.

Comment: @TRomano Yes, but the OP wrote *I have given it to her 10 minutes ago*.

Comment: Right, you were correcting his question, but OP might think you were commenting on the four possibilities.

Comment: sorry, can I change 10 minutes ago to for 10 minutes?

Comment: @Ook: "10 minutes ago" is correct. See the edits I made to your question.

Comment: @Ook Both past simple and present perfect can be used with *for* to indicate a period, but the meanings are different. 1) *I have drunk milk for 10 minutes = I still drink the milk.* 2) *I drank milk for 10 minutes = I drink milk no longer.*

Comment: @TRomano Wondering about the edit, should we omit the word "it" from the sentense?

Comment: Yes, "it" is ungrammatical there. "the milk that I gave her".